# Difference between isAuthenticated and isFullyAuthenticated

Tags: spring, spring-security

I'm trying to learn spring security, and I have question:
what is the difference between isAuthenticated and isFullyAuthenticated in spring security

Answer (score 54, accepted):

From the spring-security documentation:

```
isAuthenticated()       Returns true if the user is not anonymous
isFullyAuthenticated()  Returns true if the user is not an anonymous or a remember-me user
```

Comment: so If I don't user remember me features, there is no difference?

Comment: correct no other difference, you'd simply use isAuthenticated() instead.

Answer (score 14):

Actually, I think they explain better in the [**AuthenticatedVoter**](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/2.0.7.RELEASE/apidocs/org/springframework/security/vote/AuthenticatedVoter.html) documentation:

> The current `Authentication` will be inspected to determine if the principal has a particular level of authentication.
>
> The "FULLY" authenticated option means the user is authenticated fully
>   (ie [AuthenticationTrustResolver.**isAnonymous**(Authentication)](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/2.0.7.RELEASE/apidocs/org/springframework/security/AuthenticationTrustResolver.html#isAnonymous(org.springframework.security.Authentication)) is **false**
>   and [AuthenticationTrustResolver.**isRememberMe**(Authentication)](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/2.0.7.RELEASE/apidocs/org/springframework/security/AuthenticationTrustResolver.html#isRememberMe(org.springframework.security.Authentication)) is **false**.
>
> The "REMEMBERED" will grant access if the principal was either
>   authenticated via remember-me Or is fully authenticated. The
>   "ANONYMOUSLY" will grant access if the principal was authenticated via
>   remember-me, OR anonymously, OR via full authentication.

And in [this table of their docs](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/3.0.x/reference/el-access.html#el-common-built-in) they mention:

> `isAuthenticated()` - Returns **true** if the user is **not anonymous**
>
> `isFullyAuthenticated()` - Returns **true** if the user is **not an anonymous** *or* a **remember-me user**