# In Spring OAuth2, why is my resource still unprotected even though I have marked it in my resource server?

Tags: spring, spring-security, resources, oauth-2.0

i,

I’m using Spring 3.2.11.RELEASE with spring-security-oauth2 v 2.0.7.RELEASE.  I want to set up a resource server such that if a client properly submits their id and secret with a grant type of client_credentials, they can use the resulting token to POST data to a URL.  However, I can’t figure out how to secure that URL (I can POST to that URL even if the token is incorrect).  Below is how I’m trying to configure my resource server

```
<oauth:resource-server id="resourceServerFilter" entry-point-ref="entry"
    resource-id="writeUrl" token-services-ref="tokenServices" />

<bean id="entry" class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.LoginUrlAuthenticationEntryPoint">
    <constructor-arg value="/writeUrl" />
</bean>

<oauth:client-details-service id="clientDetails">
    <oauth:client client-id="my-client-with-secret"
        authorized-grant-types="client_credentials" authorities="ROLE_CLIENT"
        scope="read,write" secret="secret" />
</oauth:client-details-service>
```

But, as I said, POSTing data to “/writeUrl” whether or not I have a valid token is successful and I wish to lock down that URL.  How do I do that?  My complete OAuth2 application context configuration is below …

```
<http pattern="/oauth/token" create-session="stateless" authentication-manager-ref="clientAuthenticationManager" xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security">
    <intercept-url pattern="/oauth/token" access="IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY" />
    <anonymous enabled="false" />
    <http-basic entry-point-ref="clientAuthenticationEntryPoint" />
    <!-- include this only if you need to authenticate clients via request parameters -->
    <custom-filter ref="clientCredentialsTokenEndpointFilter" after="BASIC_AUTH_FILTER" />
    <access-denied-handler ref="oauthAccessDeniedHandler" />
</http>

<!-- The OAuth2 protected resources are separated out into their own block 
    so we can deal with authorization and error handling separately. This isn't 
    mandatory, but it makes it easier to control the behaviour. -->
<http pattern="/oauth/(users|clients)/.*" request-matcher="regex"
    create-session="stateless" entry-point-ref="oauthAuthenticationEntryPoint"
    use-expressions="true" xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security">
    <anonymous enabled="false" />
    <intercept-url pattern="/oauth/users/([^/].*?)/tokens/.*"
        access="#oauth2.clientHasRole('ROLE_CLIENT') and (hasRole('ROLE_USER') or #oauth2.isClient()) and #oauth2.hasScope('write')"
        method="DELETE" />
    <intercept-url pattern="/oauth/users/.*"
        access="#oauth2.clientHasRole('ROLE_CLIENT') and (hasRole('ROLE_USER') or #oauth2.isClient()) and #oauth2.hasScope('read')"
        method="GET" />
    <intercept-url pattern="/oauth/clients/.*"
        access="#oauth2.clientHasRole('ROLE_CLIENT') and #oauth2.isClient() and #oauth2.hasScope('read')"
        method="GET" />
    <custom-filter ref="resourceServerFilter" before="PRE_AUTH_FILTER" />
    <access-denied-handler ref="oauthAccessDeniedHandler" />
    <expression-handler ref="oauthWebExpressionHandler" />
</http>

<!-- The OAuth2 protected resources are separated out into their own block 
    so we can deal with authorization and error handling separately. This isn't 
    mandatory, but it makes it easier to control the behaviour. -->
<http pattern="/me/**" create-session="never"
    entry-point-ref="oauthAuthenticationEntryPoint"
    access-decision-manager-ref="accessDecisionManager"
    xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security">
    <anonymous enabled="false" />
    <intercept-url pattern="/me" access="ROLE_USER,SCOPE_READ" />
    <custom-filter ref="resourceServerFilter" before="PRE_AUTH_FILTER" />
    <access-denied-handler ref="oauthAccessDeniedHandler" />
</http>

<bean id="oauthAuthenticationEntryPoint"
    class="org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.error.OAuth2AuthenticationEntryPoint">
    <property name="realmName" value="sparklr2" />
</bean>

<bean id="clientAuthenticationEntryPoint"
    class="org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.error.OAuth2AuthenticationEntryPoint">
    <property name="realmName" value="sparklr2/client" />
    <property name="typeName" value="Basic" />
</bean>

<bean id="oauthAccessDeniedHandler"
    class="org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.error.OAuth2AccessDeniedHandler" />

<bean id="clientCredentialsTokenEndpointFilter"
    class="org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.client.ClientCredentialsTokenEndpointFilter">
    <property name="authenticationManager" ref="clientAuthenticationManager" />
</bean>

<bean id="accessDecisionManager" class="org.springframework.security.access.vote.UnanimousBased"
    xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans">
    <constructor-arg>
        <list>
            <bean class="org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.vote.ScopeVoter" />
            <bean class="org.springframework.security.access.vote.RoleVoter" />
            <bean class="org.springframework.security.access.vote.AuthenticatedVoter" />
        </list>
    </constructor-arg>
</bean>

<authentication-manager id="clientAuthenticationManager"
    xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security">
    <authentication-provider user-service-ref="clientDetailsUserService" />
</authentication-manager>

<authentication-manager alias="authenticationManager"
    xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security">
    <authentication-provider>
        <user-service id="userDetailsService">
            <user name="marissa" password="koala" authorities="ROLE_USER" />
            <user name="paul" password="emu" authorities="ROLE_USER" />
        </user-service>
    </authentication-provider>
</authentication-manager>

<bean id="clientDetailsUserService"
    class="org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.client.ClientDetailsUserDetailsService">
    <constructor-arg ref="clientDetails" />
</bean>

<bean id="tokenStore"
    class="org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.token.store.JdbcTokenStore">
    <constructor-arg ref="dataSource" />
</bean>

<bean id="tokenServices"
    class="org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.token.DefaultTokenServices">
    <property name="tokenStore" ref="tokenStore" />
    <property name="tokenEnhancer" ref="tokenEnhancer" />
    <property name="supportRefreshToken" value="true" />
    <property name="clientDetailsService" ref="clientDetails" />
</bean>

<bean id="tokenEnhancer"
    class="org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.token.store.JwtAccessTokenConverter" />

<bean id="requestFactory"
    class="org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.request.DefaultOAuth2RequestFactory">
    <constructor-arg name="clientDetailsService" ref="clientDetails" />
</bean>

<bean id="approvalStore"
    class="org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.approval.TokenApprovalStore">
    <property name="tokenStore" ref="tokenStore" />
</bean>

<oauth:authorization-server
    client-details-service-ref="clientDetails" token-services-ref="tokenServices">
    <oauth:authorization-code />
    <oauth:implicit />
    <oauth:refresh-token />
    <oauth:client-credentials />
    <oauth:password />
</oauth:authorization-server>

<oauth:resource-server id="resourceServerFilter" entry-point-ref="entry"
    resource-id="writeUrl" token-services-ref="tokenServices" />

<bean id="entry" class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.LoginUrlAuthenticationEntryPoint">
    <constructor-arg value="/writeUrl" />
</bean>

<oauth:client-details-service id="clientDetails">
    <oauth:client client-id="my-client-with-secret"
        authorized-grant-types="client_credentials" authorities="ROLE_CLIENT"
        scope="read,write" secret="secret" />
</oauth:client-details-service>

<mvc:default-servlet-handler />

<oauth:expression-handler id="oauthExpressionHandler" />

<oauth:web-expression-handler id="oauthWebExpressionHandler" />
```

Comment: Could you upload the complete source code in github or somewhere else?

Comment: Unfortunately, no.  However the entire OAuth configuration is in the XML above -- there are no other parts of my proejct that pertain to OAuth.  My question is basically how do you take a URL and secure taht as part of the resource server using an XML configuration.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There should be an `intercept-url` in the resource endpoint configuration with access restricted to authorized users (I'm guessing your url could match the following pattern)

```
   <security:http pattern="/writeUrl/**" 
                  create-session="never" 
                  entry-point-ref="oauthAuthenticationEntryPoint"
                  access-decision-manager-ref="accessDecisionManager">
     <security:anonymous enabled="false" />
     <security:intercept-url pattern="/**"
                             access="IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY"/>

     <security:custom-filter ref="resourceServerFilter"
                             before="PRE_AUTH_FILTER" />
     <security:access-denied-handler ref="oauthAccessDeniedHandler" />
   </security:http>
```

Comment: When you have "IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY" is taht in the context of SPring security or Spring OAuth2 (maybe they are hte same thing)?  I'm using the "client_credentials" grant type, but when my client submits their id and secret, I"m not sure if that makes them "IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY".

Comment: Well, in this case, I meant it in the context of OAuth2. [Also](http://stackoverflow.com/a/30953295) isAuthenticated() should be fine and make them authenticated.